# track equilibrium of periodic ode system

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to track equilibium in a periodid ode system. In such systems the equiblirium is defined as `x[t]=x[t-1]` and `y[t]=y[t-1]`. So it requires me to evaluate `x[t-1]` and `y[t-1]` when `EventCondition` takes effect within the `NDSolve` process.

For example, for such a system:

```
f[x_]:=0.1+0.05*Sin[2*Pi*(x+1/3)]; 
ressol=NDSolve[{xx'[t] == 0.2*xx[t]*y[t] - f[t]*xx[t], 
 y'[t] == (1 - y[t]) - 0.5*xx[t]*y[t], xx[0] == 0.5, 
 y[0] == 0.5}, {xx, y}, {t, 0, 200},
      Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> Abs[xx[t]-xx[t-1]]+Abs[y[t]-y[t-1]]<Power[10,-5], 
        "EventCondition" -> (t > 10), 
        "EventAction" :> {Print[ t, " ", xx[t], y[t]], 
          "StopIntegration"}}];
Plot[Evaluate[{xx[t], y[t]} /. ressol], {t, 0, 200}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

But I get the errors: `NDSolve::evre: The value of the event function at t = 9.777182689739677 was not a real number. The event will be ignored in steps where it does not evaluate to real numbers at both ends.`The reason is `xx[t-1]` and `y[t-1]` can not be evaluated within the `NDSolve` process. Can anyone help me for this issue? Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you want to do -- what does "track equilibrium" mean?  From your definition it sounds like you want to find a limit cycle with period 1, but your forcing function doesn't have period 1 (f[x] divides by 2pi instead of multiplying).  Anyhow, from numerically solving it, it looks like xx[t] goes to zero rather than a limit cycle.  Looks like a predator-prey system with periodic predator mortality.  If you want periodic behavior out, you need to let the predator xx live first!

Comment: Sorry for the mistake before! Yes, I would like to find a limit cycle with period 1.

Answer (score 2):

With your new `f[x]`, I made the event Mod[t,1], with the action to compare the current state against the previous one saved in `xxold` and `yold`.

```
f[x_] := 0.1 + 0.05*Sin[2*Pi*(x + 1/3)];
xxold = yold = 0;
tmax = 200;
ressol = NDSolve[{xx'[t] == 0.2*xx[t]*y[t] - f[t]*xx[t], 
    y'[t] == (1 - y[t]) - 0.5*xx[t]*y[t], xx[0] == 0.5, 
    y[0] == 0.5}, {xx, y}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> Mod[t, 1], 
     "EventAction" :> {If[Abs[xx[t] - xxold] + Abs[y[t] - yold] < 10^-5, 
        Throw[{xxeq, yeq, teq} = {xx[t], y[t], t}, 
         "StopIntegration"]]; xxold = xx[t]; yold = y[t]}}];

{xxeq, yeq, teq}

(* {1.99184, 0.499614, 192.} *)
```

You might want a more stringent condition than <10^-5, because it still seems to be changing a bit.

If you have Mathematica 9 or later, I think WhenEvent is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain this is correct but it seems promising. The idea is to placate `NDSolve` with a delay differential equation.

```
f[x_] := 1 + Sin[x/(2*Pi) + 1/3] + 1/2;
ressol = NDSolve[{xx'[t] == 0.2*xx[t]*y[t] - f[t]*xx[t], 
    y'[t] == (1 - y[t]) - 0.5*xx[t]*y[t], xxd'[t] == xx'[t - 1], 
    xxd[t /; t <= 0] == 0, yd'[t] == y'[t - 1], yd[t /; t <= 0] == 0, 
    xx[0] == 0.5, y[0] == 0.5}, {xx, y, xxd, yd}, {t, 0, 200}, 
   Method -> {"EventLocator", 
     "Event" -> 
      Abs[xx[t] - xxd[t]] + Abs[y[t] - yd[t]] < Power[10, -5], 
     "EventCondition" -> (t > 10), 
     "EventAction" :> (Print[t, " ", xx[t], y[t]]; 
       "StopIntegration")}];
```

We get this message:

```
NDSolve::ihist: Conditions given at t = 0.` will be interpreted as initial history functions for t/;t<=0.. >>
```

Now plot the result.

```
Plot[Evaluate[{xx[t], y[t]} /. ressol], {t, 0, 200}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]